# Python String template dict KeyError, how to set default value

Tags: python, dictionary, stringtemplate

I want try:

```
"%(name)s, %(age)s" % {"name":'Bob'}`
```

and console `Bob, 20` or `Bob,`.

But, this'll raise:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):`
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>`
    "%(name)s, %(age)s" % {"name":'a'}`
KeyError: 'age'`
```

How do I set default value? 
In fact, I want get `Bob,` when I input  `"%(name)s, %(age)s" % {"name":'Bob'}` don't raise Except.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can subclass `dict` this way:

```
class Default(dict):
    def __init__(self, default, *args, **kwargs):
        self.default = default
        dict.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return self.default
```

# Usage:

```
print "%(name)s, %(age)s" % Default('', {"name":'Bob'})
print "%(name)s, %(age)s" % Default('', name='Bob')
```

Both of lines above prints `Bob,`

[See it working online](http://rextester.com/LVRZ50186)
[See version of this code written in Python 3 working online](http://rextester.com/NEEA73777)

## Edit

I reinvited [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
from collections import defaultdict

print "%(name)s, %(age)s" % defaultdict(lambda: '', {"name":'Bob'})
print "%(name)s, %(age)s" % defaultdict(lambda: '', name='Bob')
```

[See it working online](http://rextester.com/BIZW19538)

Comment: Yeah, python3.0 that's great, but ... python2.7 will `raise TypeError: super() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)`, when I set `super(Default).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`, will `raise TypeError: must be type, not dict` ...

Comment: @张志鹏: See my edit. Also, consider mentioning about using Python 2 in question (in content or using tag).

Comment: Now I know, python2.7 must use `super(Default, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)`, try this~~

Comment: @张志鹏: If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted by clicking tick / checkmark (`✓`) in its upper left corner.

Comment: Oh, wonderful! `collections.defaultdict`, Great for you!How come you are so good

Answer (score 0):

You have used `ages` as the key while the key variable is `age`. Thus you have to write it as

```
"%(name)s, hello. %(age)s" % {"name":'a', "age":"15"}
```

This will print

```
'a, hello. 15'
```

Comment: yeah, I want this, see [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27561813/3992791), when Str have dict-Key, Dict not have the Key, set the value is "" for Str. like:`"%(name)s, %(age)s" % {"name": "Bob"}` --> `Bob, ` , or `"%(name)s, %(age)s" % {"age": 23}` --> `, 23`

Comment: @张志鹏 Oh you have edited the question. :) Didn't see that though. Now that your question has been answered already, don't mind reading my answer. *Sorry*.

Comment: @张志鹏 Anytime SO is always here to help.

Answer (score 0):

`"%(name)s, %(age)s" % {"name":'Bob'}` you didn't define any `'age'` key in your dictionary.

```
In [10]: _dict = {"name":'Bob', 'age': 20}

In [11]: "%(name)s, %(age)s" %_dict
```

or it's always better to use `string` formatting. [see the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) and it is more pythonic.

```
In [5]: "{name}s, {age}s".format(name='Bob', age=20)
Out[5]: 'Bobs, 20s'
```

by **jamylak** suggestion,

```
In [17]: "{name}s, {age}s".format(**_dict)
Out[17]: 'Bobs, 20s'
```

Comment: Yes format with keyword parameters is the best option but just in case anyone is wondering it also works with dictionaries eg. `.format(**_dict)` but the current solution is nicer of course

Comment: Oh, i want this , `"%(name)s, %(age)s" % {"name": "Bob"}` --> `Bob, `, or `"%(name)s, %(age)s" % {"age": 23}` --> `, 23`

Comment: @张志鹏 This is wrong you can't do this. `%(age)` by doing this you are saying to find `age` key in dictionary while it's not in so `raise KeyError`.

Comment: Oh, so sad. I'm writing a function, I got some value like[{}, {}] from Mysql. And I have config template like `message_template = Hello %(user)s, you have a program %(program_name)s not start, please check that.` Because mysql SQL write by config, like `query_sql = select user, id, content from program where start_time < expect_time and state=0`, state=0 is the program is not start on. SQL columns isn't certain, so when i use StringTemplate will raise KeyError...I don't want this.

Comment: @张志鹏 If columns value is `Null` then SQL will return `None` so key has value `None` then.

Comment: no no, I'm not saying this. the query_sql can be A:`'select user, id, content from program where start_time < expect_time and state=0'` or B:`'select user, id, program_name from program where start_time < expect_time and state=0'`, `message_template = Hello %(user)s, you have a program %(program_name)s not start, please...`. when I get a list[task(dict), task..] from mysql, I'll try: `message_template % task`, output a string, then send mail. when I use B, that's right, But use A, that'll raise KeyError.I'm don't want raise Error..when the key not in Dict, set value is "" for template ...